# JavaScript DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, dom, setattribute

I am working on a JSBin exercise. Here is the link:

http://jsbin.com/sevirufite/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I've taken the words out of the HEStext DIV, split them into an array, added unique spans to each word (word1, word2, word3, etc) and would like to, upon clicking the transform button, be able to mouseover each word and turn it's background yellow, then back to normal on moving (blurring?) off to another word. Grateful if you can teach me...!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so all you need is some CSS to accomplish what you want with the `:hover` rule. (You also want to clear the HTML *after* you split up the words).

Here's an updated jsbin as well as the code here, below: http://jsbin.com/muceyimoje/4/

```js
var HEStext = document.getElementById("HEStext");
var transformBtn = document.getElementById("transformButton");

transformBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var wordArray = HEStext.innerText.split(" ");
  HEStext.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    var spanNode = document.createElement("span");
    spanNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(wordArray[i]));
    HEStext.appendChild(spanNode);
    HEStext.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ')); 
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

#HEStext > span {  
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/* When we hover, change the background to yellow */
#HEStext > span:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Unit 3 Project A: Jerald Dana Cole</h1>
<p>The DIV that will serve as your input (and output) is here:

<div id="HEStext">It’s that time of year when you clean out your closets, dust off shelves, and spruce up your floors. Once you’ve taken care of the dust and dirt, what about some digital cleaning? Going through all your files and computers may seem like a daunting task, but we found ways to make the process fairly painless.
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="transformButton" name="transformButton" value="Transform!" />
```